# How do you apply a CSS to a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I was just wondering on how i'm able to apply a CSS exactly like the image below to a java generated one-page QR ticket. Attempting to tinker with the current CSS does not yield the results I expect.
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnmcP.png)

Here's the current code for the function

```
function openQRCodeWindow(registrationId) {
  var qrCodeImage = generatedQRCode._el.firstChild.toDataURL("image/png");
  var firstName = document.getElementById("first-name").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("last-name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var contactNumber = document.getElementById("contact-number").value;
  var seatNumber = document.getElementById("seat-number").textContent;

  var newWindow = window.open();
  newWindow.document.write('<style>');
  newWindow.document.write('body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; background-image: url("megapolis background.png"); background-size: cover; }');
  newWindow.document.write('.container { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; padding: 50px; border: 2px solid #ccc; border-radius: 10px; width: 400px; }');
  newWindow.document.write('.qr-container { margin-right: 20px; }');
  newWindow.document.write('.details-container { text-align: right; }');
  newWindow.document.write('.button-container { margin-top: 20px; text-align: center; }');
  newWindow.document.write('.button-container button { margin: 0 5px; }');
  newWindow.document.write('</style>');

  newWindow.document.write('<h2>QR Code</h2>'); // Place the QR code title here
  newWindow.document.write('<div class="container" id="form-container">');
  newWindow.document.write('<div class="qr-container">');
  newWindow.document.write('<img src="' + qrCodeImage + '">');
  newWindow.document.write('</div>');
  newWindow.document.write('<div class="details-container">');
  newWindow.document.write('<h3>Details</h3>');
  newWindow.document.write('<p>Registration ID: ' + registrationId + '</p>'); // Display the Firebase-generated ID
  newWindow.document.write('<p>First Name: ' + firstName + '</p>');
  newWindow.document.write('<p>Last Name: ' + lastName + '</p>');
  newWindow.document.write('<p>Email: ' + email + '</p>');
  newWindow.document.write('<p>Contact Number: ' + contactNumber + '</p>');
  newWindow.document.write('<p>' + seatNumber + '</p>');
  newWindow.document.write('</div>');
  newWindow.document.write('</div>');
  newWindow.document.write('<div class="button-container">');
  newWindow.document.write('<button id="save-image-btn">Save Image</button>');
  newWindow.document.write('<button id="email-btn">Email</button>');
  newWindow.document.write('</div>');
  newWindow.document.close();
```

I am not familiar with adding css to js functions, so I tried different in-line styles but it didn't seem to work out as expected.

Comment: @AHaworth — Yes, they have. The start and end tags for the body element are (explicitly, according to the HTML specification) optional. The body element will be implicitly created by the `<h2>` start tag.

Comment: @Quentin yes, you are of course right, they haven't explicity created it but it does get created by the browser if missing.

Answer (score -1):

Use of the document.write() method is strongly discouraged.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

You can use appendChild method to add element in qr-container.
All style can be created in style.css file. Then, you can use classList.add to add class name to element.

You code is too long, I made a simple example.

```js
function openQRCodeWindow(registrationId) {
const container = document.querySelector('.qr-container');
const titleElement = document.createElement('h1');
titleElement.textContent = 'ABC';
titleElement.classList.add('title');
container.appendChild(titleElement);
}

openQRCodeWindow('')
```

```css
.title {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class='qr-container'></div>
```

Comment: While `document.write` is discouraged, your change is so dramatic that the code no longer behaves the same way (i.e. opens a new window and generates an HTML document in it).